# What is the common and/or member pronunciation of 'Marylebone' in 'Marylebone Cricket Club'?

Tags: pronunciation

There are lots of Internet discussions on how to pronounce '[Marylebone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marylebone)'. But *given* the context of '[Marylebone Cricket Club](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marylebone_Cricket_Club)' (MCC), what is the most common pronunciation among UK people and/or MCC members?

Comment: It is pronounced exactly as 'Marylebone', the place, would be. I am no expert in how to write phonetically. John Lawler and various others would know how to do that. But you don't say 'Mary le bone'. It comes across as two syllables something like 'MARILLE-BUN'.

Comment: @WS2 I pronounce it 'marleybone' with the 'marley' as in Bob and the bone as in 'skull and cross..'. _Towcester_ is a gem too as is _Woolfardisworthy_. (I'm not a member of the MCC though).

Comment: @Frank You are certainly not alone, and when I was a Norfolk lad I may well have called it the 'Mary Le Bone'. But the RP pronunciation is 'Marrillebun'.

Comment: @WS2 Thank you. After some further digging I found [this link](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/marylebone-cricket-club) with sound. Do you agree on the BrE pronunciation that can be heard there? (I still wonder about Frank's pronunciation though, because it maybe how the members speak. For a cricketer it has a familiar ring to it.)

Comment: @GlenTheUdderboat Yes, that is the 'correct' pronunciation. MARLEY BONE may be an ironic pronunciation that members use, a bit like kitchen staff in a posh restaurant may refer among themselves to the 'horse's doovres' when they mean *hors d'oeuvres*.

Comment: @WS2 It's the _bun_ that I don't do - I do the _marley_ right, which means it's probably not right for 'Bob'. Can't please everybody!

Comment: [Don’t be fooled by the way it is sometimes spelled ‘Mary-le-bone’. And don’t be side-tracked by the history of the name – it was originally named after a church called St. Mary’s by the Bourne. There’s no ‘Mary’ when you pronounce ‘Marylebone‘ – you say ‘mar/li/bone’ or ‘mar/li/bun’](http://www.howdoyousaythatword.com/english-words/pronounce-london-place-names/). I do hear people using the [Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/marylebone) version, but in my experience that's less common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct pronunciation is "ma-ruh-luh-buhn". This is how it is pronounced in this British Pathe newsreel from 1968: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8VyVUw_EktI at 0:30 and by the automated announcer on Chiltern Trains (the railway company that serves that station). The pronunciation by the automated announcers on the London Underground ("Mar-lee-bone") is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Marralabone or Marrylabone. Hope that helps. I used to work in Marylebone High Street, so that's what we all called it at the BBC.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary, the most common British pronunciation is ['mær əl ə bən], and the most common American pronunciation is 
['mer əl ə boʊn], which to my ear match the audio files in the Oxford Learner's Dictionary, see [here](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/marylebone).

Two of the less common variants are ['mær ɪ bən] and ['mɑːl ɪ bən].

Answer (score 2):

As a (former) north-Londoner, born to north-London parents married at Marylebone registry office, I would agree with @Amgine. Thus, borrowing @painfulenglish's phonetics, it is ['mærə ləboʊn] or ['mærɪ ləboʊn]. This was the only London district about whose pronunciation I had recurring doubt. I suspect that no single pronunciation can be pinned down as standard.

Answer (score 0):

The way you pronounce Marylebone has been a famous marker of social class or education for at least 200 years. (You can find references in literature if you want to research it).
Upper class or educated say: "Marley-bun".
Working class say: "Marruh-bun".
Lower middle class/non-U or uneducated (and non-Londoners) say: "Marry-luh-bone".